# Node.js - two connections in Chrome and Safari?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, safari, node.js, v8

I'm trying this basic Javascript code in Node.js:

```
var count=1;
var net = require('http');
net.createServer(function(req,res){
    res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type':'text/plain'});
    res.end((count+=1).toString());
}).listen(3000,"127.0.0.1");
```

**Expected result**: Each browser hit increments the count output by 1.

**Actual result:** Firefox increments by 1 (expected)... Safari + Chrome increment by *2*

Huh?

Comment: As for firebug, as stated, Firefox works fine. I would like to find out why Safari + Chrome don't. I would assume anyone with knowledge of either browser would be able to answer this fairly easy, without resorting to network sniffers.

Comment: I guess the answer is: favicon.ico

Comment: @Gonzalo, smart thinking, I never considered that! If you want to put that in an answer, I'd be happy to accept it... that's almost a d'oh moment!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, as the comments suggested, it's `favicon.ico`.

Next time log `req.url` before guessing around :)

Comment: Good tip - console.log(req)... I didn't think to check initially, as I said, a d'oh moment!

Answer (score 2):

I guess the answer is: `favicon.ico` :-)